# Spark Accumulator in custom Aggregator

Tags: apache-spark, accumulator, aggregator

I have a custom aggregator and in the reduce method I would like to use an accumulator to do some statistics.

How should I pass the accumulator to the aggregator?

Do I have to pass the accumulator as a constructor param or do i have to use the `AccumulatorContext.get(0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the accumulator outside of your aggregator (and outside of any other code that will be running on an executor node) and use it within the aggregator. The variable itself can be passed around like any other normal variable.

```scala
val ds = sc.parallelize(1 to 5).toDS()
val acc = sc.longAccumulator
val mySumAgg = new Aggregator[Int, Int, Int] {
  def reduce(b: Int, a: Int): Int = {
    acc.add(1)
    a + b
  }      
  [...]
}.toColumn

ds.groupByKey( i => i)
  .agg(mySumAgg)
  .show()

print("Merge has been called " + acc.value + " times")
```

If you have created a separate class for your aggregator, you can pass the accumulator via a constructor or you might use a setter.

You should not use [AccumulatorContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/util/AccumulatorContext.html), as the docs say:

> An internal class used to track accumulators by Spark itself.